# Converting multiple columns variable into dummy variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm thinking to convert multiple columns of categorical variables in a data frame to dummy variables using pandas. The code below works, but it seems too long. May I know how do I combine these 3 lines in a single line of code, please? Thank you

```
X = pd.get_dummies(df.height, prefix=['height'])

Y = pd.get_dummies(df.weight, prefix=['weight'])

Z = pd.get_dummies(df.age, prefix=['age'])**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=["height", "weight", "age"])
```

Comment: Thanks the code works well but I would like to save these 3 variables into another variable called "J".  so I used J = pd.get_dummies(data=df, columns=["height", "weight", "age"]). However, 2 other columns in the original data frame appear as well. How do I exclude these 2 columns?

Comment: A possible approach could be to create a list with the new column names: `new_cols = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]` and then create the new dataframe as `J = J[new_cols]`.

Comment: @NicoleOppenheim for clarity, please provide the expected output